# SecKeyRawSign giving a -50 (errSecParam) error - even for the trivial apple example

Tags: iphone, ios, x509, pki

Having trouble to get a very basic version of SecKeySign() to work (I.e. porting a working OSX SecSignTransformCreate()/SecTransformSetAttribute()/SecTransformExecute() to iOS):

The code is pretty much as per http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_SecKeyWrapper_m.html - albeit even further simplified.

First up - setting things up - as per above link. No changes.

```
const char someData[] = "No one loves pain itself, but those who seek...";

NSData * blob = [NSData dataWithBytes:someData length:sizeof(someData)];
assert(blob);

SecKeyRef publicKeyRef, privateKeyRef;
int keySize = 2048;

OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
NSMutableDictionary * privateKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary * publicKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary * keyPairAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// attribute dictionaries for 2048 bit RSA key pair.
//
[keyPairAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[keyPairAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:keySize] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits];
[privateKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];
[publicKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];
[keyPairAttr setObject:privateKeyAttr forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs];
[keyPairAttr setObject:publicKeyAttr forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPublicKeyAttrs];
```

And the actual work starts with generating a keypair:

```
sanityCheck = SecKeyGeneratePair((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyPairAttr, &publicKeyRef, &privateKeyRef);
assert(sanityCheck == noErr);

NSLog(@"Pub/Priv: %@/%@", publicKeyRef, privateKeyRef);
```

which works splendidly insofar as I can see.

The trouble is with using them to sign; or rather the signing:

```
// Zero-ed Buffer for the signature.
//
size_t signatureBytesSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKeyRef);
assert(signatureBytesSize == keySize / 8);

uint8_t * signatureBytes = malloc( signatureBytesSize * sizeof(uint8_t) );
memset((void *)signatureBytes, 0x0, signatureBytesSize);

// Sign the binary blob; with type 1 padding.
//
sanityCheck = SecKeyRawSign(privateKeyRef,
                            kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                            (const uint8_t *)[blob bytes], [blob length],
                            (uint8_t *)signatureBytes, &signatureBytesSize
                            );
assert(sanityCheck == noErr);
```

which always returns a -50/errSecParam (One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.).

Any suggestions ? This is on an actual iPhone ?

Thanks,

Dw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insofar as I can work out - the only acceptable inputs for SecKeyRawSign() are a data block of SHA_DIGEST_LEN. Anything else is rejected.

The SHA1 hash is calculated by this function - so one only needs to pass the needed space.

I've not yet found a way to specify a SHA2 or other hash.

Dw

Comment: That would make sense if you didn't pass in a hash algorithm. But when I specify PKCS1SHA1 as the second argument the docs suggest that it hashes first (producing a data block of SHA_DIGEST_LEN) which it then does the signing on. So I'm not sure then whether I should hash myself first or rely on the function to do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

My Xcode iOS Unit Test project was failing, with all Keychain related APIs returning -50. I fixed it by creating a new target "single page" App, and setting it as the host for the unit test. [How to take iOS Framework testing target and run it in a dummy app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423941/how-to-take-ios-framework-testing-target-and-run-it-in-a-dummy-app)