# How to take iOS Framework testing target and run it in a dummy app?

Tags: ios, xcode

So I am running into an issue where my Framework needs access to the `KeyChain`. That's fine, but it seems to fail when running in the simulator. Digging around it seems to be a known issue that `xctest` does the wrong thing here. Fair enough, bugs happen. In the Apple Developer forums it's discussed here:

> Right.
>
> This is a well-known issue with library tests (sometimes called logic tests by Xcode).  Those tests are run by a tool (xctest) that does not have entitlements.  Historically this caused problems for folks using custom entitlements (to access CloudKit, for example) but now it affects folks using the keychain as well.
>
> AFAIK there’s no direct workaround.  **However, I believe you can avoid the problem by running this test code within your app** (emphasis mine) (in the docs this is called an app test).
>
> Because these run inside your app, they get the app’s entitlements.
>   If you don’t have an app handy, **you can create a dummy one just to host the tests.** (emphasis mine  **how do I do this?**)
>
> Please try this out and let us know if you hit any snags.
>   Oh, and don’t let the availability of a workaround prevent you from filing a bug about this.  Xcode should be able to run library tests with entitlements, and this recent keychain change makes this even more important.
>   Share and Enjoy

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/179846 (see: Eskimo's reply on Nov 4, 2016 2:12 AM)

He again goes on to say in another reply:

> - **You can avoid the problem by running your tests within an app, creating a dummy app if you don’t have one handy.** (emphasis mine)
> - Feel free to file your own bug about this limitation.

So again he references:

**You can avoid the problem by running your tests within an app, creating a dummy app if you don’t have one handy.**

I'm more than happy to do this, I just can't seem to figure out how.

The parts I have:

```
Framework Project
    |
    |- Unit Test Target
    |- Framework Target

Dummy App Project
    | 
    |- ??? How do I make this run the Framework's Unit Test Target?
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ah, this article helped:

https://medium.com/@ryuichi/setup-host-app-for-keychain-tests-in-xcode-8-97222611917e#.z3zpqwnzt

I was adding a totally new app project, I just needed to add a new Target in the Framework project for a `Single View Application`

That then allows me to select `Host Application` in the testing target.

Using my previous diagram, the final result that worked is:

```
Framework Project
    |
    |- Unit Test Target
    |- Framework Target
    |- Dummy App Target
```

[image]